# Knockout two-way binding to object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, knockout.js

I am trying to use Knockout.js to create a two-way binding between a javascript object and some DOM elements. I want my object to reflect the changes in the DOM elements and vice versa. I successfully achieved the first goal, the vice versa part I can't get to work however.

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KirkOlson/sywyqhLt/)

```
myPerson = {
    firstName : "",
    lastName : "",
    age  : null,
    test : function() {alert('Testing');}
};

myViewModel = function myViewModel(obj) {
    this.firstName = ko.observable();
    this.lastName = ko.observable();
    this.age = ko.observable();
    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        obj.firstName = (this.firstName() || '');
        obj.lastName = (this.lastName() || '');
        obj.age = (this.age() || '');

        return (this.firstName() || '') + ' ' + (this.lastName() || '');
    }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel(myPerson));



    //How to get property changes reflected in the DOM inputs?
```

When I make changes in the DOM inputs the properties of the myPerson object change accordingly. Next step is changing these properties manually and automagically see these changes reflected in de DOM inputs. I tried messing around with the mapping plugin but no cigar so far.

Comment: Do you want the `myPerson` object to change when your observables do??

Answer (score 2):

Using just KO, just changing the properties of your `myPerson` object will not change your viewmodel, and so will not update the DOM.

The "KO way" is to just have the viewmodel, not `myPerson` separate from it, and update that viewmodel by calling the observables as functions, e.g.:

```
myViewModel.firstName("TheNewFirstName");
```

On **modern browsers**, you *could* define your properties on `myPerson` using accessor functions, which could then raise an event or similar that the view model would watch for, but this requires features added in ECMAScript5 (~2009) which are present in modern browsers, but not IE8 and earlier. It also would mean effectively having a double viewmodel (`myPerson` and `myViewModel`).

So when using KO, you typically just have the viewmodel itself, and call the observables to update them.

Here's a simple example "the KO way":

```js
var vm = {
  counter: ko.observable(0)
};
ko.applyBindings(vm, document.querySelector('div'));
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  if (vm.counter() >= 20) {
    clearInterval(timer);
  } else {
    vm.counter(vm.counter() + 1);
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div>
  <span data-bind="text: counter"></span>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

---

If you're only looking to support modern browsers and want something KO-like that works with plain objects like your `myPerson`, you might look at  [RivetsJS](http://rivetsjs.com/), which applies getters/setters to your objects for you.

Here's that same simple example done with Rivets — but it won't work on pre-ECMAScript5 engines:

```js
var obj = {
  counter: 0
};
rivets.bind(document.querySelector('div'), obj);
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  if (obj.counter >= 20) {
    clearInterval(timer);
  } else {
    ++obj.counter;
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div>
  {counter}
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rivets/0.8.1/rivets.bundled.min.js"></script>
```

(This is not a *recommendation*, just noting the option. I've happily used KO in proper projects; never had the chance to do the same with Rivets.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Using your rivets example is there a way to have {counter} in an input element instead of in a div?

Comment: @KirkOlson: Yup, looks like you use the `rv-value` binding (it's shown on the first page of the site) (I'm not a RivetJS expert): `<input rv-value="counter">`